# Google places api quota calculation error

Tags: google-places-api

I tried to used the google places api but after 9 requests my quota is 9%. Normaly i should have 1000 requests per day, so reality is 100 requests per day.

Could you tell me what is the problem ?

Best regards

Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

the Google Places API using Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota.  That is one thing that may explain your problem.

That said my quota is at 54% and I am getting an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT message so not sure what my problem is.